# JarFile / ZipFile caching?

Tags: java, jar, io, zip

I need to verify a signed jar from my application. I found I can do it by reading all contents, like this:

```
public boolean verifyJar(String filePath) {
    try {
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(filePath, true);
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(entry);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            while (is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != -1) {
                // we just read. this will throw a SecurityException
                // if a signature/digest check fails.
            }
            is.close();
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I execute the checker with a valid jar, it passes. If I corrupt the jar by cutting it in half, it fails. But if I do both in one process, the second check passes (as if it read the previous version of the file)!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String path = "src/test/resources/temp/lib.jar";
    // Passes - that's good
    System.out.println(new Validator().verifyJar(path));

    byte[] content = FileUtil.readFile(path);
    FileUtil.save(path, Arrays.copyOf(content, content.length / 2));
    // Passes - but it shouldn't.
    // Fails if the first check is commented out though.
    System.out.println(new Validator().verifyJar(path));
}
```

So it looks like `ZipFile` or `JarFile` is cached somehow. How do I suppress this behavior?

Comment: i will tip you up, use ZipFile.close method

Comment: @bestsss That did the trick, thanks! Feel free to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZipFile has to be closed in order native code not to cache. Iirc ZipFile wraps the same handle (*jzfile*) if the path and File.lastModified are the same.

Alternatively touching File.lastModified may do the trick too but closing anything open manually (incl. ZipFile) is necessary to prevent resource leaks.